# How to get the date a week in the past from today?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate

I know how to get the date in iOS. I need to find last weeks date. So for example if today is 05/27/2011, I need to be able to get 05/20/2011

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for NSDate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
    NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDate * date = [NSDate date];

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    [components setWeek:-1];

    NSDate * lastweek = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];

    NSLog(@"%@", lastweek);

    [components release];
```

Comment: Yes. This would be the elegant way. :)

Comment: awesome i didn't know you can simply subtract like that

Answer (score 6):

This is crude but would work:

```
NSDate *prevWeekDate = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(-60 * 60 * 24 * 7)];
```

Click for detail on [dateByAddingTimeInterval:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: shouldn't there be a negative in there?

Comment: wouldn't it increase the date in 7 days, instead of decrease it?

Comment: This looks good to me, so under which conditions is this solution crude? I don't see any cons except feb 29th of a leap year? But maybe that would work out ok to?

Comment: My way works but @Desdenova's is the Apple way. Thus it is the "more correct" way.